# Adding a column to data frame and populating it given a conditional statement

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a data frame that looks like this in structure but is 50000 rows long:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3), Y = rnorm(14), Z = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"))
```

I want to have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(X = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3), Y = rnorm(14), Z = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"), NEW = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2))
```

In words: I have different objects (A,B in this case; column Z). On each object measurements were taken at different locations, e.g. 1,2,3,4 happened on object A at location 1. 1,2 happened on object A at location 2. Now I'd like to add a column that designates the location like the column NEW in df2.

I can't figure out a conditional statement that could do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: `df$NEW <- c( ... values ... )`

Comment: What about this needs to be conditional?  Your question is currently very unclear to me

Comment: So every time you see X=1, you want to swap the location from 1 to 2 or vice versa?

Comment: Your conditional rule is not clear. Can you clarify the composition of NEW in terms of X, Y, Z?

Comment: I'd like to add the NEW column (location) without going through 50000 rows manually and adding everything individually. I only have column X and Z to get to column NEW as specified in example df2. I was wondering if there is a way automating this with a conditional statement or a loop.

Comment: How do you know your `data.frame` is ordered correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
df$NEW <- with(df, ave(X, Z, FUN=function(x) cumsum(c(TRUE, x[-1] < x[-length(x)]))))
```

Comment: This is a slight variation of the same idea `with(df, ave(X, Z, FUN=function(x) cumsum(x==1)))`